# Exception when running OpenJPA 2 native query with Derby DB

Tags: ejb-3.0, derby, openjpa

While running below native query 
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM  INVOICES  ", Object[].class).getResultList();
this exception is thrown

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Schema 'SA' does not exist
                at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
                ... 89 more
Caused by: ERROR 42Y07: Schema 'SA' does not exis

My tables are under my schema comp and if I change the query to below one it is working fine

em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM  comp.INVOICES  ", Object[].class).getResultList();

but I do not want to do that , any body can help to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you asking how the default schema is determined? Or are you asking about the `SET SCHEMA` SQL statement? Or are you asking how to put your tables under a different schema? Or maybe you are asking something else entirely?

Comment: No , I am asking why OpenJPA look for explicit schema name in SQL string when I define the schema that the table is under that in JPA setting, my goal is that to run native named query without explicit schema name in SQL string